# react-native-single-choice usage without using hooks

Tags: react-native, react-native-component

I want to use this library react-native-single-choice but in a simple class component. I am not using hooks so I am kind of not able to use in my class.
Link to the documentation:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-single-choice

Comment: Which hook do you want to use in your class component?

Comment: No hook. basically, I need to know the format how I can write the same code(in the link) in a class component.

Comment: You want to use `useState` hook?

Comment: No, I dont want to use that